# Clock problem when waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, time, clock

When waking from suspend, time settings changes to manual, and time on my PC is sometimes 5 days from current time. That causes difficulties using time-related programs, such as chats... When I change to automatically after waking, after 10-15 minutes, time gets normal.

How can I fix this issue?

I'm using 16.04, but i had this problem on earlier versions too.

Comment: Your problem is hardware, not software.

Comment: Some machines don't have a working realtime clock (RTC) unit, or no
 driver for the hardware that does exist. *fake-hwclock* (from the default Ubuntu repositories) is a simple set  of scripts to save the kernel's current clock periodically (including at shutdown) and restore it at boot so that the system clock keeps at  least close to realtime.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have? What's the manufacturer and model?

Answer (score 4):

Install Network Time Protocol daemon and utility programs (*ntp*).

```
sudo apt install ntp fake-hwclock
```

NTP, the Network Time Protocol, is used to keep computer clocks  accurate by synchronizing them over the internet or a local network.

To set the hardware clock to the current system time by syncing the hardware clock with the system clock:

```
sudo hwclock -w
```

Comment: `sudo` is needed to access `hwclock` whether reading or writing.